# DOS redirecting output not working

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a Windows program that I call inside a .BAT file like this:

```
.\my_prog.exe param1
```

If I just call it like that, from a cmd or powershell window I get some output. However, if I redirect the output to some file, it does not work. If I write:

```
.\my_prog.exe param1 >out.txt 2>&1
```

`out.txt` is empty after execution of my script is over.

`my_prog.exe` is a proprietary binary and I don't have access to the code.

It is worth mentionning that I have a linux version of the same script that calls a binary compiled for linux. I had the same issue, but I managed to work around it by using the script command:

```
script -c "./my_prog.lx param1"
```

I can't find an equivalent of "script" and cygwin is not an option unfortunately.

Thanks for your help

EDIT:

After digging up more, I found out that my program does not flush the buffer when the output is written to another source than STDOUT. Now, my best shot at this is to trick my program into thinking that it is writing to STDOUT, is there a way of doing that in BAT or wurh powershell ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Could you please clarify what you are asking?

Comment: what is not clear for you from my question ?

Comment: Does the script run and not produce any output or does it not run at all?

Comment: it runs and the binary does what it is supposed to do, it's just the output that i can't get(and i REALLY would like to have it)
plz check the linux part as well, i think it's relevent to the issue here, unfortunately, i am more familiar with linux than windows

Comment: _if I redirect the output to some file, it does not work_. In addition  to @SomethingDark comment: please, tell us (preferably editing your question): 1. launching `.\my_prog.exe param1`, then output is some text to command line window? 2. launching `.\my_prog.exe param1  >out.txt 2>&1`, then output to command line window is the same or another text?

Comment: There could be something in the parameters breaking the redirection, like a `|` or a `&`

Comment: two ideas: First: try `>out.txt 2>&1 ( .\my_prog.exe param1 )` (with and without the parantheses). Second: a few programs use stream 3 for output (don't ask why...). So try an additional `3>&1`